# How to get iphone information by serial number or IMEI?

Tags: iphone

It seems that we can get iphone information, such as ICCID, active date, color, storage size and so on, by serial number or IMEI on apple's website before. But this is not allowed these days, at least by apple's public website.

But I found an APP that can do this. It just use serial number to get all these information including the phone number and mobile operator. So I think apple's website still have this kind of API/service. Anybody knows?

Comment: for what purpose are you trying to gather this personal information? and your question is very broad, do you want to detect all of the info related to the device or for example just a specific data? i suggest reading up on uidevice documentation and within it you will see the documented methods. apple is tightening up the extraction of user device data, so posting it on dev forum is not a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but my question is not related to ios API. I want to gather these information is that I can get the new ICCID or phone number when the device is stolen.

Comment: There is no official way of obtaining it. You have to use the telecommunication company's software for that. Those apps that you referring to probably use the software from telecom companies. That is the only way to obtain the info you are looking for as far as know. I had to research a bit though, good question.